# redshift unrecognized node type 407

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am developing a synchronization mechanism to move data form aws redshift to aurora. In order to lower the load on network I/O I am transforming the queries on redshift and add them a checksum query so I will export only the records that have changed. I am wrapping the base query with another Select * query and adding the a checksum function.

I have tried to remove some inner sub queries and after that the new query is working, but I can't change the query since is provided by some other platform.

Base Query:

```
select x.player_id as playerid,
                                    p.player_nickname, 
                                    r.region_code,
                                    s.title as season_name,

                                    x.rating as ranking_score,
                                    x.rank_no as rank_no,
                                    x.rank_no_change as rank_no_change,

                                    x.game_mode, 

                                    to_char(ga.total_score, 'FM9D00') as gyo_perf_total_score,
                                    to_char(agressive_score*100/aggresive_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_aggressive_score, 
                                    to_char(defensive_score*100/defensive_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_defensive_score, 
                                    to_char(survival_score*100/survival_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_survival_score,

                                    ga.match_place_avg,

                                    rounds_played, 

                                    kills, 
                                    (kills*1.0)/rounds_played as avg_kills_per_round,
                                    assists, 
                                    (assists*1.0)/rounds_played as avg_assists_per_round,
                                    headshot_kills, 
                                    top10s, 
                                    (top10s*1.0)/rounds_played as top10s_ratio,
                                    wins, 
                                    (wins*1.0)/rounds_played as win_ratio,
                                    case when top10s = 0 then 0 else (wins*1.0)/(top10s*1.0) end as win_to_top10_ratio,
                                    losses,
                                    ga.match_group as ___matchgroup,
                                    ga.last_update_id as ___lastupdateid_ga,
                                    ___lastupdateid_st,
                                   x.last_update_id as ___lastupdateid_rn

                 from hd_stats.calc_player_ranking x
                       inner join hd_core.core_player p on x.player_id = p.player_id 
                                                           and p.player_game_id =
                                                           (select g.game_id 
                                                                                    from hd_core.core_game g 
                                                                                    where lower(g.game_short_title) = 'xxxx')

                       left join hd_core.core_region r on x.region_id = r.region_id
                       left join hd_core.core_season s on x.season_id = s.season_id

                       --gyo perf
                       left join hd_stats.calc_pubg_gyo_average ga on 
                                             ga.player_id = x.player_id 
                                             and nvl(x.season_id,0) = nvl(ga.season_id,0)
                                             and nvl(x.region_id,0) = nvl(ga.region_id,0)
                                             and nvl(x.game_mode,'') = nvl(ga.match_mode,'')

                       left join (select player_id, region_id, 
                                         season_id, match_mode,
                                         rounds_played as rounds_played, 
                                         kills as kills, 
                                         assists as assists, 
                                         headshot_kills as headshot_kills, 
                                         top10s as top10s, 
                                         wins as wins,
                                         losses as losses,
                                         lastupdate as ___lastupdateid_st

                                     from hd_stats.calc_pubg_player_season_stats s
                         ) as y 
                         on x.player_id = y.player_id
                         and nvl(x.season_id,0) = nvl(y.season_id,0)
                         and nvl(x.region_id,0) = nvl(y.region_id,0)
                         and nvl(x.game_mode,'') = nvl(y.match_mode,'')
                      order by ___lastupdateid_rn
```

Transformed Query that fails:

```
Select top 100 *
,func_sha1(
''
)
as synch_checksum
 from 
(
select x.player_id as playerid,
                                    p.player_nickname, 
                                    r.region_code,
                                    s.title as season_name,

                                    x.rating as ranking_score,
                                    x.rank_no as rank_no,
                                    x.rank_no_change as rank_no_change,

                                    x.game_mode, 

                                    to_char(ga.total_score, 'FM9D00') as gyo_perf_total_score,
                                    to_char(agressive_score*100/aggresive_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_aggressive_score, 
                                    to_char(defensive_score*100/defensive_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_defensive_score, 
                                    to_char(survival_score*100/survival_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_survival_score,

                                    ga.match_place_avg,

                                    rounds_played, 

                                    kills, 
                                    (kills*1.0)/rounds_played as avg_kills_per_round,
                                    assists, 
                                    (assists*1.0)/rounds_played as avg_assists_per_round,
                                    headshot_kills, 
                                    top10s, 
                                    (top10s*1.0)/rounds_played as top10s_ratio,
                                    wins, 
                                    (wins*1.0)/rounds_played as win_ratio,
                                    case when top10s = 0 then 0 else (wins*1.0)/(top10s*1.0) end as win_to_top10_ratio,
                                    losses,
                                    ga.match_group as ___matchgroup,
                                    ga.last_update_id as ___lastupdateid_ga,
                                    ___lastupdateid_st,
                                   x.last_update_id as ___lastupdateid_rn

                 from hd_stats.calc_player_ranking x
                       inner join hd_core.core_player p on x.player_id = p.player_id 
                                                           and p.player_game_id =
                                                           (select g.game_id 
                                                                                    from hd_core.core_game g 
                                                                                    where lower(g.game_short_title) = 'xxxx')

                       left join hd_core.core_region r on x.region_id = r.region_id
                       left join hd_core.core_season s on x.season_id = s.season_id

                       --gyo perf
                       left join hd_stats.calc_pubg_gyo_average ga on 
                                             ga.player_id = x.player_id 
                                             and nvl(x.season_id,0) = nvl(ga.season_id,0)
                                             and nvl(x.region_id,0) = nvl(ga.region_id,0)
                                             and nvl(x.game_mode,'') = nvl(ga.match_mode,'')

                       left join (select player_id, region_id, 
                                         season_id, match_mode,
                                         rounds_played as rounds_played, 
                                         kills as kills, 
                                         assists as assists, 
                                         headshot_kills as headshot_kills, 
                                         top10s as top10s, 
                                         wins as wins,
                                         losses as losses,
                                         lastupdate as ___lastupdateid_st

                                     from hd_stats.calc_pubg_player_season_stats s
                         ) as y 
                         on x.player_id = y.player_id
                         and nvl(x.season_id,0) = nvl(y.season_id,0)
                         and nvl(x.region_id,0) = nvl(y.region_id,0)
                         and nvl(x.game_mode,'') = nvl(y.match_mode,'')
                      order by ___lastupdateid_rn
 )
```

Transformed Query that works:

```
Select top 100 *
,func_sha1(
''
)
as synch_checksum
 from 
(
select x.player_id as playerid,
                                    p.player_nickname, 
                                    r.region_code,
                                    s.title as season_name,

                                    x.rating as ranking_score,
                                    x.rank_no as rank_no,
                                    x.rank_no_change as rank_no_change,

                                    x.game_mode, 

                                    to_char(ga.total_score, 'FM9D00') as gyo_perf_total_score,
                                    to_char(agressive_score*100/aggresive_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_aggressive_score, 
                                    to_char(defensive_score*100/defensive_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_defensive_score, 
                                    to_char(survival_score*100/survival_weight, 'FM9D000') as gyo_perf_survival_score,

                                    ga.match_place_avg,

                                    rounds_played, 

                                    kills, 
                                    (kills*1.0)/rounds_played as avg_kills_per_round,
                                    assists, 
                                    (assists*1.0)/rounds_played as avg_assists_per_round,
                                    headshot_kills, 
                                    top10s, 
                                    (top10s*1.0)/rounds_played as top10s_ratio,
                                    wins, 
                                    (wins*1.0)/rounds_played as win_ratio,
                                    case when top10s = 0 then 0 else (wins*1.0)/(top10s*1.0) end as win_to_top10_ratio,
                                    losses,
                                    ga.match_group as ___matchgroup,
                                    ga.last_update_id as ___lastupdateid_ga,
                                    ___lastupdateid_st,
                                   x.last_update_id as ___lastupdateid_rn

                 from hd_stats.calc_player_ranking x
                       inner join hd_core.core_player p on x.player_id = p.player_id 
                                                           and p.player_game_id = 2
                                                           --(select g.game_id 
                                                           --                         from hd_core.core_game g 
                                                           --                         where lower(g.game_short_title) = 'xxxx')

                       left join hd_core.core_region r on x.region_id = r.region_id
                       left join hd_core.core_season s on x.season_id = s.season_id

                       --gyo perf
                       left join hd_stats.calc_pubg_gyo_average ga on 
                                             ga.player_id = x.player_id 
                                             and nvl(x.season_id,0) = nvl(ga.season_id,0)
                                             and nvl(x.region_id,0) = nvl(ga.region_id,0)
                                             and nvl(x.game_mode,'') = nvl(ga.match_mode,'')

                       left join (select player_id, region_id, 
                                         season_id, match_mode,
                                         rounds_played as rounds_played, 
                                         kills as kills, 
                                         assists as assists, 
                                         headshot_kills as headshot_kills, 
                                         top10s as top10s, 
                                         wins as wins,
                                         losses as losses,
                                         lastupdate as ___lastupdateid_st

                                     from hd_stats.calc_pubg_player_season_stats s
                         ) as y 
                         on x.player_id = y.player_id
                         and nvl(x.season_id,0) = nvl(y.season_id,0)
                         and nvl(x.region_id,0) = nvl(y.region_id,0)
                         and nvl(x.game_mode,'') = nvl(y.match_mode,'')
                      order by ___lastupdateid_rn
 )
```

Expected to get all the records and columns on the base query and another column for the checksum.

Instead I get an error :

Amazon Invalid operation: unrecognized node type: 407; [SQL State=XX000, DB Errorcode=500310]

Comment: That must be a bug in Redshift; you should report it. Can you highlight the difference between your queries and format them better?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just replaced ``` (select g.game_id 
                                                                                    from hd_core.core_game g 
                                                                                    where lower(g.game_short_title) = 'xxxx'') ``` with value 2 because that is the value that it will return

Comment: Yes, that must be a bug.

Comment: it seem to be a problem with SQL Workbench Query Editor, cause running form code it worked fine.

Comment: I had a similar issue when creating views with sub-queries/CTEs and it appears that Redshift doesn't like it. I changed my SQL where statement to avoid using subqueries, and now it works!! Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 12):

Leave out the ORDER BY clause. That alleviated the error for me.